# In ag-grid is it possible to display in the same column a cell with a check-box and another type

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

In ag-grid on Angular  is it possible to display in the same column  a cell that contains a check box and another cell that contains a list box depending og the data in the cell ?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom cell renderer. The section "Many renderers one column" in the documentation may help: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/